# Для чего нужны данные макросы в Си в заголовочном файле inttypes.h

Tags: c, макросы

Для чего нужны данные макросы SCNxN и PRIxN. Например:

```
  #include <inttypes.h>

// В функции считывания данных
uint32_t code_point;

fscanf(in, "%" SCNx32, &code_point);

printf("%" PRIx32, code_point);
```

Comment: Да просто чтоб не запоминать, какие там для какого типа правильные буквочки писать...

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим как они задаются в `<inttypes.h>`:

```
# define PRIx32   "x"
...
# define SCNx32   "x"
```

Т.е. вместо них в данном примере будут проставлены "x" и:

```
fscanf(in, "%" SCNx32, &code_point);

printf("%" PRIx32, code_point);
```

станет:

```
fscanf(in, "%x", &code_point);

printf("%x", code_point);
```

А само `%x` обозначает число в шестандцатеричном отображении.